# Complex query, many joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been wrestling with this for a few hours and I'm hoping you can give me some fresh insight.  I have 6 tables as follows:

- Table A
- Table B, which is a child of A (one-to-many)
- Table C, which is a child of B (one-to-many)
- Table D, which is a another child of A (one-to-many)
- Table E is another parent of D, in a one-to-[zero-or-one] relationship
- Table F, which is another child of E (one-to-many)

Basically I need to select a field from B where C = F.

I have tried with subqueries, joins, and a combination of both, but have not got too far.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information you've presented, how about

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A
        INNER JOIN B ON B.AID = A.AID
        INNER JOIN C ON C.BID = B.BID
        INNER JOIN D ON D.AID = A.AID
        INNER JOIN E ON E.DID = D.DID
        INNER JOIN F ON F.EID = E.EID
WHERE   C.Field = F.Field
```

If this is not what you need, you might want to post a small subset of data with the required results.

Comment: +1 for getting all of the JOINs spelled out.  The OP would have to tell us what is going wrong.  Too many rows? (cuz of those 1-m), coming up empty? What is not happening?